# Problem with Feature Extraction using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working on Acute Lymphoblastic Leukemia Detection using images of blood samples. I'm having a problem separating out the white blood cells from each other during the extraction part.

The code of what I have done so far is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
from skimage import io, color
import cv2

noOfImages = 12
for i in range(1,noOfImages):
    print('Run #', i)

    path = 'Data/' + str(i) + '.jpeg' #path to img
    rgb = io.imread(path)
    lab = color.rgb2lab(rgb) #coverting to lab colorspace for kmean clustering
   #cv2.imwrite( 'labImage'+str(i)+'.jpeg',lab)

    singlePrecisionImage = skimage.img_as_float32(lab)
 

    twoDimage = singlePrecisionImage.reshape((-1, 3))
    twoDimage = np.float32(twoDimage)
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    K = 3
    attempts = 10

    ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(twoDimage, K, None, criteria, attempts, cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)
    center = np.uint8(center)
    res = center[label.flatten()]
    result_image = res.reshape((rgb.shape))
   #cv2.imwrite('outClusteredImg' + str(i) + '.jpeg', result_image)

   #coverting the img to binary
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(result_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, bw_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
   #cv2.imwrite('outbinary'+str(i)+'.jpeg', bw_img)

   #applying erosion and dilation to seperate the white blood cells
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 2))
    erosion = cv2.morphologyEx(bw_img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

   #masking the orignal image with eroded image
    bitwiseImg = cv2.bitwise_and(rgb, rgb, mask=erosion)
   #cv2.imwrite('outBitwise'+str(i)+'.jpeg', bitwiseImg)

   #extracting cells
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(bitwiseImg,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    idx =0 
    for cnt in cnts:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(bitwiseImg, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        roi=bitwiseImg[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        #cv2.imwrite('blastCell_' + str(idx) + '.jpeg', roi)
        idx += 1
    cv2.imwrite('outLocalization'+str(i)+'.jpeg', bitwiseImg)
```

Now, the problem is that some of the white blood cells in the image even after eroding are still too connected with each other, so they do not really get correctly separated/marked by the bounding boxes.

The images and the resulting image are provided below:

Original Image:

[image: Orignal Image]

Final Bounding Box Image:

[image: Final Bounding Box Image]

Original Image:

[image: Orignal Image]

Final Bounding Box Image:

[image: Final Bounding Box Image]

Is there any solution for this? What else can I do to detect those white blood cells separately?

Comment: Erode (do not open) and binarize. To restore the original size, dilate the bounding boxes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Tried that, to correctly separate the cells had to use kernal (35, 30) which makes the size of cells quite small but correctly separates the cells tho. Now can't really get the original size back. Applying dilation changes shape of cells quite a lot like from circle/oval to rectangular shape etc 
`for cnt in cnts:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        roi=bitwiseImg[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        dialted = cv2.dilate(roi, kernel)
        cv2.imwrite('Feature/blastCell_' + str(idx) + '.jpeg', dialted)
        idx += 1`

Comment: also 'roi' size/dimensions is already decided because of x,y,w,h cordinates before dilating. even if i dilate, it will only consider the part of roi that falls under image dimension and will ignore everything out of it.

Comment: I said dilate the bounding boxes (over the original image).

Comment: @YvesDaoust , oh, my bad. Any guidance on how do I do that? As per my understanding the bounding box is being made using x,y,w,h values. How do I dilate these values over the orignal image? I'm new to computer vision so any help is appreciated

Comment: hem, like x-3,y-3,w+6,h+6.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, oh that actually make sense. So manual dilation. I was thinking about that  opencv dilation function. Thanks for the help!